# Expose service in a path using Marathon-lb

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, mesos, marathon, dcos

I want to expose on a path 
I use [HAPROXY_{n}_PATH](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/blob/master/Longhelp.md#haproxy_n_path), according to docs I have to use a VHHOST.

When I use both, I get this:

```
frontend marathon_http_in
  bind *:80
  mode http
  acl host_foo_bar hdr(host) -i foo.bar.com
  acl path_foo_bar path_beg /foo-bar
  use_backend foo_bar if host_foo_bar path_foo_bar
```

What I need is something like this:

```
frontend marathon_http_in
  bind *:80
  mode http
  acl host_foo_bar hdr(host) -i foo.bar.com
  acl path_foo_bar path_beg /foo-bar
  use_backend foo_bar if host_foo_bar or path_foo_bar
```

Comment: Adding a new ACL to the service would work and removing the HAPROXY_{n}_PATH. I have to add the VHOST part, or else HAPROXY_0_HTTP_FRONTEND_ACL won't work. https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/issues/457

The problem now is that I can't add multiple ACLs, using "\n".

Comment: HAPROXY_0_HTTP_FRONTEND_ACL = 
  acl host_foo_bar hdr(host) -i foo.bar \n 
  acl path_is_foo_bar path_beg /foo-bar \n    
  use_backend use_backend foo_bar_80 if path_is_foo_bar \n  
  use_backend use_backend foo_bar_80 if host_foo_bar \n